# PySerial: Create serial object without opening port

Tags: cgi, arduino, pyserial

I'm running some code on Arduino, I have website with a slider which uses a cgi script to pass values to Python. Then the python script uses pySerial to send the values to Arduino which controls a motor.

The plan was to be able to control the motor speed using the slider on the website.

However I seem to be coming up against a problem of the Arduino resetting whenever I change a value on the website, causing the motor to stop. Is there any way around this? My python code is below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cgi
form=cgi.FieldStorage()

import json

ser = serial.Serial('dev/ttyACM0', 9600) 
#I think there should be a sleep here for 1.5 seconds
ser.write("%s\n" % (form["value"]))
ser.close()

print "Content-type: application/json"
print
print(json.JSONEncoder().encode({"status":"ok"}))
```

So, say I have the motor running at 50% speed, then change a value on the website, it runs this script which executes the `serial.Serial('dev/ttyACM0', 9600)`  command. That opens the port which resets the arduino, stopping the motor before passing the new command.

Is there any way to pass  `ser.write("%s\n" % (form["value"]))`  to the arduino without freshly opening the port? Such as leaving the port open between python sessions?

If not, is there any other way around this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the reset is due to a hardware design of the specific Arduino device you are using. I suggest using an Arduino Micro or Leonardo board instead. They use a virtual serial port and  should not restart your sketch each time a serial port is opened. This is from the Arduino site:

> **[No reset when you open the serial port.](http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoLeonardoMicro?from=Guide.ArduinoLeonardo#toc3)**
>
> Unlike the Arduino Uno, the Leonardo and Micro won't restart your
>   sketch when you open a serial port on the computer. That means you
>   won't see serial data that's already been sent to the computer by the
>   board, including, for example, most data sent in the setup() function.
>
> **Serial re-enumeration on reset.**
>
> Since the boards do not have a dedicated chip to handle serial
>   communication, it means that the serial port is virtual -- it's a
>   software routine, both on your operating system, and on the board
>   itself. Just as your computer creates an instance of the serial port
>   driver when you plug in any Arduino, the Leonardo/Micro creates a
>   serial instance whenever it runs its bootloader. The board is an
>   instance of USB's Connected Device Class (CDC) driver. This means that
>   every time you reset the board, the USB serial connection will be
>   broken and re-established. The board will disappear from the list of
>   serial ports, and the list will re-enumerate. Any program that has an
>   open serial connection to the Leonardo will lose its connection. This
>   is in contrast to the Arduino Uno, with which you can reset the main
>   processor (the ATmega328P) without closing the USB connection (which
>   is maintained by the secondary ATmega8U2 or ATmega16U2 processor).
>   This difference has implications for driver installation, uploading,
>   and communication...

Comment: From searching around I think this is the answer, it appear to be just the way it is. There are hardware ways around it involving soldering, but I don't want to get into that. Will have to take a different approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I you might be able to use the `setDTR(False)`, but I have tested this yet. A while back they fixed the bug that were initially associated with setDTR. What operating system are you use this on?

```
ser = serial.Serial('dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
ser.timeout = 1
ser.setDTR(False)
```

Let us know if this does not work.

Comment: Thanks John, but i'm afraid this didn't work... what should ser.setDTR(False) do?